# Javascript Psychic Game

Tags: javascript

I am creating a guessing game and am trying to get a condition that doesn't allow my user to choose the same answer twice.  I was thinking somehow say if the userGuess is not equal to an item in the empty span (user guesses) I created then nothing happens.  Am new to javascript and just needed some direction!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Psychic Game</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="game">
  <h1> The Psychic Game </h1>
  <p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of!</p>
  <p>Wins:</p>
  <p>Losses:</p>
  <p>Guesses Left:</p>
  <p>Your Guesses so far:</p>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  
   var computerChoices = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",];

   var wins = 0;
   var losses = 0;
   var numGuesses = 9;
   var guessChoices = [];

   document.onkeyup = function(event) {

    var userGuess = event.key;

    var computerGuess = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];

    var options = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",];
    

   if (options.indexOf(userGuess) > -1) {

    if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
     wins++;
     numGuesses = 9;
     guessChoices = [];
    }

    if (userGuess != computerGuess) {
     numGuesses --;
     guessChoices.push(userGuess);
    }

    if (numGuesses === 0) {

    numGuesses = 9;
    losses ++;
    guessChoices = [];

    
   }

   var html = 
   "<h1> The Psychic Game </h1>" +
   "<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of!</p>" +
   "<p>Wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
   "<p>Losses: " + losses + "</p>" +
   "<p>Guesses Left: " + numGuesses + "</p>" +
   "<p>Your Guesses so far: " + guessChoices.join(", ") + "</p>";

   document.querySelector("#game").innerHTML = html;

   
   }
  };

 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really provide something we can work on and not just asking us to develop the logic. I know you're a complete beginner but still StackOverflow is for helping developers, not writing code for them.

Comment: at least post some code for others to know what you have tried so far.

Comment: In the process of trying to post the code but I am new to the site and it would not let me.  hold on.

Comment: Got it uploaded. Sorry for the ambiguity up front.

Answer (score 0):

If you created an array of the user's answers so far

```
var userAnswers = [];
```

and made it so that whenever you answered, it would check all the previous answers to see if it matched one.

```
var isDuplicate = false;
for (var i = 0; i < userAnswers.length; i++) { //for every previous answer
    if (currentAnswer == userAnswers[i]) { //check if the current answer is a previous one
        isDuplicate = true;
        break; //exit loop
    }
}
if (!isDuplicate) { //different than previous
    userAnswers[userAnswers.length] = currentAnswer;
    //do other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the array.includes method to check if guessChoices includes the user's  current guess, would look something like this:

```
if (options.indexOf(userGuess) > -1) {
    if (userGuess === computerGuess) {
        wins++;
        numGuesses = 9;
        guessChoices = [];
    }
    else {
        if (guessChoices.includes(userGuess)) {
            // Code for duplicate guess
        }
        else {
            numGuesses--;
            guessChoices.push(userGuess);
        }
    }

    if (numGuesses === 0) {
        numGuesses = 9;
        losses++;
        guessChoices = [];
    }
}
```

However you are resetting the computer's guess on every keypress so it may give some unintended results.